# WordPress: how to change the category page title to just the category name?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I need to change the page title of [this page](https://ibros-dev.com/category/news). I created this page from the category. So the page title is showing the category name. I need to change that page title to *News*.

I couldn't find an option or setting to change the title so need to change the title by using custom CSS.

[image]

This is what I see when I check the coding of the page:

[image]

Please help me change the page name to **News** instead of **Category: News**

Comment: do you want to remove Category: right?

Comment: Are you using a theme? if so which one? There are often templates for category-pages, that you can edit.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in your `functions.php` file

```
function change_category_page_title( $title ) {
    $title_arr = explode(':', $title);
    if ( count($title_arr) > 0 ){
        if(array_key_exists(1, $title_arr)) {
            return $title_arr[1];
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'change_category_page_title', 9999 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter `get_the_archive_title` for that:

```
function set_archive_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $parts = explode( ':', $title );
        
        unset( $parts[0] );
        
        $title = trim( implode( ' ', $title ) );
    }
    
    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'set_archive_title' );
```

This splits the string in array parts for every occurring `:`. Then the first part of the array gets removed and then the remaining parts are changed back to a string.